# Override size of bootstrap datepicker for mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker on my app. Everything works fine except when i'm triying to change the size of the calendar.

I've found the next CSS code online and it works, but change the size on desktop version and mobile.

```
.datepicker,
.table-condensed {
  width: 500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

Any sugestions to keep two sizes of datepicker; one for desktop and one for mobile?

I'm using AngularJs, Javascript, and Bootstrap datepicker.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a media query to specify the size of the date picker on mobile.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .datepicker {
        width: 100px;
        height:100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx. I'll try. Just a little doubt: i need to specify two times the code? What i mean: put the first code (the code i've put on the question), and then the query, or just need one (your sugestion)?

Comment: I do not have your exact code, so add both. The first css of 500 px should apply for desktop screens.